# How to Add a File in .git Directory to Track It?

Tags: git

**I need to track a single file in the `.git/` directory (a .gitkeep) but I cannot figure a means to do so.**

The reason is I have a boilerplate that needs the `.git/` directory because a "third-party UI module" initiates `git init` where I tell it. The problem is if the directory does not exist, the init fails by default to another directory and then the tracking tree becomes incorrect from what I need. (*Weird, I know.*) however I need to have an empty `.git/` directory for the application install.

**I have tried the following:**

```
$ git add web/app/.git/.gitkeep
```

**But I receive a:**

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>   web/app/.git/.gitkeep Use -f if you really want to add them.

*This is not true since I do not have a `.gitignore`.*

**Next I tried:**

```
$ git add web/app/.git/.gitkeep -f
```

**..And I get:**

> error: Invalid path 'web/app/.git/.gitkeep' error: unable to add
>   web/app/.git/.gitkeep to index fatal: adding files failed

***This is not true either, the file is valid.***

Any ideas would be very helpful. I thought to just add it manually to the remote repo but I think(??) this would cause issues...?

**UPDATE:**

*I failed to say* that the `.git/` directory was needed to exist after our application install. I understand that pushing the `.git` directory is a bad security No No - esp. when I preach it but I was only needing to push an empty `.git` directory to the repo for the reason stated above.

For those who need an empty `.git/` directory and is using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36536653/742030).

Answer (score 4):

### ***`You should not have any files inside .git folder !!!`***

Here is a very detailed post about the content of this folder:
http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html

---

***`This folder is for internal use only to store the git content and more.`***

---

**From the below article:**

> Just one word of wisdom when messing around with Git internals: ***`make sure you know what you’re doing`***, and if not, have a backup! Messing around with the config files or hooks is pretty simple but I wouldn’t go spelunking in the datastore if I didn’t have to. If for some reason you are as part of your normal workflow, you might be doing it wrong.

**Screen shot from this article:**

[image]

Comment: Please read the question again - I did not ask to push the contents of the entire .git/ directory only a .gitkeep to keep the folder. Also see my reply to @MrTux The tick downs are for rushing the read of the question. Also I now of developers who checkin their hooks and settings residing in the .git/ directory.

Comment: When you add content to git NOTHING from the `.git` folder is added or tracked in git. so you cant place any file inside it (for tracking)