# If someone removed submodule, how do others remove it too?

Tags: git, github

For example, there is a github project called `test`, and there is a `subtest` submodule inside it.

Then one day the maintainer removed submodule `subtest` and pushed it to github,

then if I do a `git pull`, will git automatically remove a `submodule` related files? like `.gitmodule` `.git/modules`???

Comment: if this "related files" are removed in the repo, after the maintainer push, then you'll get them removed too. and tracked by git (not ignored) then normally yes

Comment: even the files in `.git` ?

Comment: From the point of view of a Git repository, a submodule inside that repository is treated similar to any other file.  If someone else deleted the submodule and pushed, when you pull it should be gone.

Comment: git automatically ignores `.git` folder, and it's better to keep it that way (cf. this  [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535991/how-to-add-a-file-in-git-directory-to-track-it))

Comment: So, it depends on your project structure, is the "sub-module" are actual files/folder outside .git, if yes, you have already the answer. else, then more info is needed